# Google Recaptcha submit with jQuery validate

Tags: jquery, recaptcha

I use last version of ReCaptcha (the invisible one).

I understood how to use it with normal forms, and Ajax forms, but I face a little problem.

I want to use the Captcha with jQuery validate plugin, so I use:

```
<form id="myForm" action="send.php" method="post">
    <h4>Your name</h4>
    <input type="text" name="name" required="required" />
    <div id='recaptcha' class="g-recaptcha"
        data-sitekey="***************"
        data-callback="onSubmitForm"
        data-badge="bottomleft"
        data-size="invisible"></div>    

    <input type="submit" value="Send form" class="button">
</form>
```

And in my JS:

```
function onSubmitForm(data) {
    if ($("#gRecaptchaResponse").val() == '') {
        $("#gRecaptchaResponse").val(data);
    }
    $('#myForm').submit();
}  

$(function() {
    $('#myForm').validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // execute google recaptcha
            grecaptcha.execute();
            
            // test fires everytime of course ...
            console.log('Test');
        }
    });
});
```

I understand in the Google example from official doc (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible#example) they handle click on a button (not a submit button), but I want to use the submit trigger, this way, the user can press "Enter" button to submit the form.

But right now, there is a kind of loop, jQuery validate handles form submit, and after validation, executes the callbacks which submits the form... Then the form is never submitted (to PHP action). The result is pretty weird.

Any simple way to keep using submit trigger?